# systemctl start service with shell_exec() [Provisory fix]

Tags: php, systemd, shell-exec, systemctl

I've been trying for the **past six hours** to start and stop a service via **systemctl** inside a PHP webpage...

I've already:

- checked the php.ini on the php8.0-fpm
- already added the www-data (shell_exec('whoami');) PHP user to /etc/sudoers
- Checked the AppArmor and SELinux for conflicts with PHP. (it can create dirs, use fopen() etc)

The thing is, it **can** use `systemctl is-active service@name`, but **cannot** start or stop a process.

```
<?php
$name = $_GET['n'];
$cmd = "start";**
$service = "service@$name";

shell_exec("sudo systemctl $cmd $service");
```

> trying to sudo does not work either.

*I'm using nginx with php8.0-fpm*

**Edit**:
got it working using `chmod u+s /usr/bin/sudo` but I think that it's not safe enough...

Comment: I don’t know your full setup, but giving PHP sudo privileges scares me. You might have this protected with NAT, auth, firewall, VPN, whatever, but it is still a Pandora’s box. If this were my system, I’d have a queue that the web can submit to, and I’d have another script running in elevation that checks that queue, that is only aware of a limited number of commands/services.

Comment: @ChrisHaas I've checked the sudo privileges with `echo shell_exec("sudo ls 2>&1; echo $?");` it only works with the `systemctl start/stop service@[subname]`

I don't know for certain if I have opened the Pandora's box, but at the moment everything seems fine according to the */etc/sudoers.d/service-starter*